# How to solve Checkmarx Codegate Issue of "Potentially sensitive personal information is sent over the unsecured network via message" -Spring boot

Tags: spring, message, checkmarx

```
public class ForseeEmailService 
{

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Value("${forsee.emailservice.email}")
    public String fromAddress; //= "samsfor@wal.com";
        publci void composeEmain(..)
        {
               ..
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));// Checkmarx Codegate Blocker
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, getRecipients());
               ..

        }
}
```

I tried move the hardcoded value of fromAddress to Azure Keyvalut and read from there still the issue is persistent.

Entire message : Potentially sensitive personal information **fromAddress**, at line **128** of **src\main\java\com\samsclub\forsee\services\ForseeEmailService.java**, is sent over the unsecured network via **message**, in **composeAndSendEmail** of **src\main\java\com\samsclub\forsee\services\ForseeEmailService.java**, line **151**. This could expose this personal data and allow it to be stolen.

**Similarity ID: -1504140421**

Comment: did you got any solution?

Comment: Not yet. Do you have any soultion? Please share